# Lync & Remote Desktop Connections

Tags: automation, remote-desktop, lync

Situation:
My organization has "Unified Communication" with Microsoft Lync.  I occasionally have to sit at another desk, so I use a remote desktop connection to continue using my usual computer.  This means I have to log out of Lync on my usual computer so I can log into Lync at the other one.  When I return to my usual computer, I never remember to log back into Lync.

Question:
Is there a way I can automate the process?  Like, can I do something so that every time I start a remote session with my usual computer, it automatically exits Lync, and every time I end a remote session it automatically starts Lync up again?

My experience is limited to simple batch files and Visual Basic, but I'm pretty good at learning just enough of something to do simple tasks.

Any input is appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lync will let you log in to multiple devices simultaneously, or end-points as Microsoft calls them. If your usual computer is locked, that device should "detect" you as away. If you are logged in to another computer, THAT one will display your presence as Available, unless you manually change your status.

There is no reason to log off of the usual computer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to log out of Lync at your usual computer? Lync lets you sign in to multiple devices, and will generally do the right thing in ensuring you receive any IMs/calls.

So when you switch machines, you could just sign in on the new machine, leaving the old logged in.

Or is there a specific reason why this doesn't work for you?

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that my usual computer is locked while I am remotely logged into it. The phone status reads "Out of Office," even though on both computers, Lync says I'm "available."