# Lync & Remote Desktop Connections, Revised

Tags: automation, remote-desktop, lync

I originally submitted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914454/lync-remote-desktop-connections), but I ran into the same problem I had before and realized I was asking the wrong thing.  (For whatever reason I thought the issue was me being logged into two computers.)

Situation: When the receptionist goes to lunch, I sit at her desk and connect to my computer remotely.  However, she locks the computer rather than logging off, so she is still signed in to Lync. From what I understand, Lync is not designed to support multiple users logged into one work station at a time. This is apparent in that I receive calls, but cannot answer them--the "notice" pops up on my screen, and then disappears when I pick up the phone.

My first thought was maybe there was a way to configure her computer to log out of Lync when the computer locks, and then log back in when she unlocks it.  (Like how you automatically log out when you shut down, and (have the option to) automatically log in when you start the computer.)  Does this sound feasible?

Any other suggestions/methods are welcome as well.  I know this could be easily solved by her logging out of Lync when she goes to lunch, but doing it automatically would be better in case she forgets. (There are other situations where she might leave and I sit at her desk that can come up suddenly, too, so it's even less likely she'd remember during those.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Lync Client SDK to close Lync ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/hh348186%28v=office.14%29.aspx)) would force a sign out,and would also make the singing in a bit easier as you could just invoke the Lync exe and it will sign you in automatically. It also avoids you running into any multi-instance problems that might happen if you have instances of Lync running on the machine, one signed in and one not.

I've never tried, but I'm sure a .net app could react to the computer being locked/unlocked. There must be a sign-in state or something?